# how to store the multiple url of images in an array

Tags: xcode5

`imgarray` is an array in which all URLs are there from where we have to parse the images and insert them into the array.I am using the below code:

```
for (int i=0; i<[imgarr count]; i++){
    imgurl=[imgarr objectAtIndex:i];
    [[JMImageCache sharedCache] imageForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgurl] completionBlock:^(UIImage *downloadedImage){                
        UIImage *image=downloadedImage;                    
        [_pageImages addObject:image];                
    }];
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: what does you actually wanted to do??? you are getting image URL's from an array then why you want to store URL's ??

Comment: sorry guys,the question is i m getting array with 1 object only.why it is happening??